# I Want to call multiple javascript function from codebehind on button click. it works fine for 3 javascript function but not more than that

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a requirement to call 4 java script function from codebehind page of asp.net page it works fine for 3 javascript function but if i add 4th which is a validation function. The validation function works but not the other 3.

This works!

```
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "return Getprodsize('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "');return formatSpecifications('" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "');return Getselectedvalue('" + hdndrop.ClientID + "')";
```

This doesnt work...

```
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "return Validate();Getprodsize('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "');return formatSpecifications('" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "');return Getselectedvalue('" + hdndrop.ClientID + "')";
```

```js
function Validate() {
  var existing = $("#ctl00_contentMain_lblProductleft").text();
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_txtProductName').val() == '') {
    $('#ctl00_contentMain_txtProductName').focus().css("border-color", "red");
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_Txtbrandname').val() == '') {
    $('#ctl00_contentMain_Txtbrandname').focus().css("border-color", "red");
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_Txtstock').val() == '') {
    $('#ctl00_contentMain_Txtstock').focus().css("border-color", "red");
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_Txtprice').val() == '') {
    $('#ctl00_contentMain_Txtprice').focus().css("border-color", "red");
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_txtShortDescription').val() == '') {
    $('#ctl00_contentMain_txtShortDescription').focus().css("border-color", "red");
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_txtLongDescription').val() == '') {
    $('#ctl00_contentMain_txtLongDescription').focus().css("border-color", "red");
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_ddlbcatgory option:selected').val() == 0) {
    alert("Please Select Catagory");
    return false;
  }
  if ($('#ctl00_contentMain_txtdeleverycharge').val() == 0) {
    $('#ctl00_contentMain_txtdeleverycharge').focus().css("border-color", "red");
    return false;
  }
  var txval = $('input[name=optradio]:checked').val();
  $('#<%=hdnTax.ClientID%>').val(txval);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple `return` statements in the `onClientClick` attribute. The first one will return, and the rest will not be executed. You should call the other functions without using `return`, and then return the value from the `Validate()` function.

```
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "Getprodsize('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "'); formatSpecifications('" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "'); Getselectedvalue('" + hdndrop.ClientID + "'); return Validate();";
```

If you want to check the validation first, and not call the other functions if it fails, you use `if`

```
    btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "if(Validate()) {Getprodsize('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "'); formatSpecifications('" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "'); Getselectedvalue('" + hdndrop.ClientID + "'); return true;} else return false";
```

It would be easier if you moved all this logic out to a new function, and just called that function in `OnClientClick`.

```
function validateAndFormat(sizeID, specID, dropID) {
    if(Validate()) {
        Getprodsize(sizeID); 
        formatSpecifications(specID); 
        Getselectedvalue(dropID); 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "validateAndFormat('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "', '" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "' + "', '" + hdndrop.ClientID + "');"
```